# Nuxeo platform unable to conenct to Elasticsearch node configured on same or locahost

Tags: elasticsearch, nuxeo

Failed to connect to elasticsearch, check addressList and clusterName: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{10.240.206.26}{10.240.206.26:9200}]
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to connect to elasticsearch, check addressList and clusterName: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{10.240.206.26}{10.240.206.26:9200}]
    at org.nuxeo.elasticsearch.core.ElasticSearchAdminImpl.checkClusterHealth(ElasticSearchAdminImpl.java:254)
    at org.nuxeo.elasticsearch.core.ElasticSearchAdminImpl.connect(ElasticSearchAdminImpl.java:137)
    at org.nuxeo.elasticsearch.core.ElasticSearchAdminImpl.(ElasticSearchAdminImpl.java:121)
    at org.nuxeo.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchComponent.start(ElasticSearchComponent.java:197)
    at org.nuxeo.runtime.model.impl.RegistrationInfoImpl.start(RegistrationInfoImpl.java:341)
    at org.nuxeo.runtime.model.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.startComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:571)
    at org.nuxeo.runtime.model.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.start(ComponentManagerImpl.java:629)
    at org.nuxeo.runtime.osgi.OSGiRuntimeService.startComponents(OSGiRuntimeService.java:460)
    at org.nuxeo.runtime.osgi.OSGiRuntimeService.frameworkEvent(OSGiRuntimeService.java:475)
    at org.nuxeo.osgi.OSGiAdapter.fireFrameworkEvent(OSGiAdapter.java:232)
    at org.nuxeo.osgi.application.loader.FrameworkLoader.doStart(FrameworkLoader.java:226)
    at org.nuxeo.osgi.application.loader.FrameworkLoader.start(FrameworkLoader.java:125)
    at org.nuxeo.runtime.deployment.NuxeoStarter.start(NuxeoStarter.java:120)
    at org.nuxeo.runtime.deployment.NuxeoStarter.contextInitialized(NuxeoStarter.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5068)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5584)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:679)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1966)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2017-09-25 18:51:07,417 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] [org.nuxeo.elasticsearch.audit.ESAuditBackend] Activate Elasticsearch backend for Audit
2017-09-25 18:51:07,417 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] [org.nuxeo.runtime.model.impl.RegistrationInfoImpl] Component service:org.nuxeo.ecm.platform.audit.service.NXAuditEventsService notification of application started failed: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.nuxeo.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchComponent.getClient(ElasticSearchComponent.java:265)

Comment: Following Elasticsearch.yml content   cluster.name: nuxeoCluster1
 node.name: nuxeo
 transport.host: 10.240.206.26 
 transport.tcp.port: 9300 
 http.port: 9200
 network.host: 0.0.0.0

Comment: You should set `network.host` instead of `transport.host`